# Repository where I can find old / obsolete ISO3166 codes of countries including previously existing ones

Tags: data-request, geocoding

Where can I find old ISO3166 codes for countries including the ones that do not exist anymore, changed their name, etc.? I need this for all years 1961 through 2021. All I could find online was up to date ISO3166 codes.